# the 2 functions are not working together but the first is only working

Tags: json, flutter, dart, conditional-operator

```
 Message.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    toId = json['toId'].toString();
    msg = json['msg'].toString();
    read = json['read'].toString();
    type = json['type'].toString() == MessageEnum.image.name
        ? MessageEnum.image
        : MessageEnum.text == MessageEnum.video.name
            ? MessageEnum.video
            : MessageEnum.text;
```

Well I have a problem in this code noting that the first part in the TYPE works and the second don't please need help

Answer (score 0):

The second condition should again check for `json` value.

```
type = json['type'].toString() == MessageEnum.image.name
        ? MessageEnum.image
        : json['type'].toString() == MessageEnum.video.name
            ? MessageEnum.video
            : MessageEnum.text;
```